# Radius convergence of power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

How would I go about finding the radius of convergence using a limit ratio test? Can I get a hint for this one?

$\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(jx)^j}{j!}$

Answer (score 2):

You can use ratio test. The $j$-term is equal to 
$$a_j=\frac{(jx)^j}{j!}.$$
Therefore, 
$$\left|\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{[(j+1)x]^{j+1}}{(j+1)!}}{\frac{(jx)^j}{j!}}\right|=\frac{(j+1)^{j+1}|x|}{j^j}\cdot\frac{j!}{(j+1)!}
=\frac{(j+1)^j}{j^j}|x|=\left(1+\frac{1}{j}\right)^j|x|.$$
Therefore, we have 
$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}\right|=\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{j}\right)^j|x|=e|x|.$$
Therefore, $\lim_{j\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}\right|<1$ if and only if $e|x|<1$, i.e. $|x|<\frac{1}{e}$.

Now you also need to check whether the series converges at $x=\frac{1}{e}$ and at $x=-\frac{1}{e}$. I will leave these to you.

Comment: No, you don't need to check the endpoints.  The question was only "radius of convergence".

Comment: @GEdgar It's only on MSE that we see people work for more than what they're paid for. It should be encouraged.

Comment: Actually, since the OP asked only for a *hint*, we maybe should downvote a complete solution.

Comment: That's fine, GEdgar. It was nice to use this to check my answer. It is my privilege, not my right to get _free_ math help from experts. The trouble I had with this question was not recognizing the _e_ limit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}|x|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\frac{k!}{k^k|x|^k}=\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k|x|\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{} e|x|\stackrel ?<1\ldots$$

Comment: + 1 for providing what the OP asked for: a hint (a strong hint, but it's the only answer that comes short of "giving it all away!)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might write the test ratio as

$$ | \frac{(j+1)^{j+1} \cdot x^{j+1} \cdot j!}{j^{j} \cdot x^{j} \cdot (j+1)!} | $$

$$ = | (j+1) \cdot ( 1 + \frac{1}{j} )^{j} \cdot \frac{1}{j+1} \cdot x |$$

$$ = | ( 1 + \frac{1}{j} )^{j} \cdot x |  .$$

Now you have something which is relatively simple to take the limit of as $j \rightarrow \infty$  .

Answer (score 0):

Let $ a_n=\frac {n^n}{n!}$then $\frac {a_{n+1}}{ a_n  }=(1+\frac {1}{n})^n  $obviosly $ \lim\frac {a_{n+1}}{ a_n  }=e $

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to factor $(jx)^j$ into $j^j$ and $x^j$. Then, use the ratio test. The ratio becomes $[(j+1)^(j+1)x]/(j^j)(j+1)$, $x \to \infty$, or $x*[(j+1)/(j)]^(j+1)$, $x \to\infty$. This diverges for all $x$.