# Convergence of the function series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(nx)^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, sequence-of-function

> Determine $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the series
> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(nx)^n}{n!}$$
> converges punctually.

I tried everything, but I'm really stucked. The book says that the series converges for $0 \le x <e^{-1}$. I tried with the ratio test, the infinitesimal test, I tried to do also $\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{(nx)^n}{n!}$ to see where the succession is infinitesimal, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/360001/42969 – both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%20_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cdfrac%7B(nx)%5En%7D%7Bn!%7D%24)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I did bad the calculation in the ratio test..